Quote - the second replicator will be free
Looking for a quote, I think it was in an essay by  Clarke or Asimov. It was speculating about the possible future development of a device similar to a Star Trek style replicator.   The quote was along the lines of, the first one will be very expensive to build. The second one will be free.
It may have been written before Star Trek TNG was broadcast, and probably didn't use the word "Replicator".

That's a wonderful premise! You're sure it was from an essay and not from a single book or series?

Not totally sure, no.  It was certainly non-fiction. I think it was an essay in a collection of essays. Most likely one of Clarke's, maybe one of Asimov's. Possibly someone else.

Clarke explicitly spoke about "replicators" of this type by name in 1964, at least: https://youtu.be/YwELr8ir9qM?t=565  Sadly this doesn't contain the phrase being asked about.

thanks, but that isn't the one.

Basically any software, literature, tv show or film.  The first copy is 100% of the expense, the second copy is free.

Did George O. Smith write any essay about his Venus Equilateral stories? They were all about the development and implications of replicator technology.

My brain thinks it's a Larry Niven or Jerry Pournelle idea.

Murray Leinster may not have come up with the idea for the replicator but his "The Fourth Dimensional Demonstrator" story, which came out in the thirties has to be a very early example.
